# How do I configure different ringtone profiles in WP8?

Tags: 8.0, ringtone

It seems I can only switch btw. silent/ringtone on the quicktoggle of the volume control and all other settings need to be changed individually under settings>...

How do I configure (ringtone) profiles in Windows Phone 8? Do I need an app for this?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible in WP7 or 8, unfortunately.

Comment: Is there an app/live tile that at least takes me directly to the ringtone settings page?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to develop such an app. It will be in the Windows Phone Store within a month. Please be patient.

I will update my answer here, when it is published.

Comment: So it is possible to do this via the phone APIs? Good news I guess :-)

Comment: I know it is possible because this app is doing it: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/meme-soundboard/d9bbce61-49d8-43ca-b6b7-a9b6389fd447

Comment: Any progress on your app?

Comment: No, sorry. I have been working on other stuff and this project has been prioritized down. I will post when I start developing again.